# Can the lensing effect of Sagittarius A* be used to image the stars diametrically opposite to the sun?

Tags: observational-astronomy, milky-way, gravitational-lensing, sagittarius-a

The sun can magnify an image of a source 100 ly away nearly 100 billion times, if the ring is captured from the nearest focal point (550AU). According to [Christian Ready of Launch Pad Astronomy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NQFqDKRAROI), we can image objects closer than 100 ly even more precisely. If this is the case, then, given that we are much much far away from Sag A*'s nearest focal point, and that the ratio of our distance from lens to the object we want to observe is much much higher than the 550 AU to 100 ly ratio for the sun, can't we image the stars on the exactly opposite side of the milky way, along the focal line of Sag A*? If yes, how precise will we be, in imaging them as well as their planets (and moons, if possible)? On that side, what is the minimum distance of an object from Sag A*, that can be imaged on earth? Can the distinct stars in the globular cluster be imaged this way? Also, can we use the sun and Sag A* as a combined lens to obtain better images?